# How to override allauth.urls in django allauth?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I would like allauth framework for Django only for social login without another functions.
I have added next in url.py (r'^social/', include('allauth.urls')), but from this I need only next url http://myapp/**social/facebook/**. How do I can override allauth.url or maybe use other way for this? I don't need any social/login, social/logout or other, because I use other auth backend.

Comment: I was looking for the same answer. In fact I just wanted to use their social media integration, but I don't think it is possible. I will have to change to another auth app.

Comment: ya, python-socail-auth is more usefull

Comment: Is it? I will try it out. Allauh is great but it installs a bunch of unnecessary things I don't want in my code. URLs you don't use and stuff. Thanks for the info.

Comment: It is. I used it in current project. There aren't any unnecessary urls, but it is very flexible. I added only social integration and it works charm.

Comment: are you having any problems with it? They don't update it since 2013. I see a lot of things don't work anymore, such as Facebook updating the user's profile.

Comment: Not yet :) But I don't have built-in methods in allauth module(like get_avatar_url) , Solved that wrote own piplines. By the way python-social-auth is supported current. Look at https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth